# How can I set a Calendar with UTC time?

Tags: java, date, utc

The posters [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java) say that Date is always in UTC time. However, if I create a Date(), create a Calendar, and set the calendar time with the date, the time remains my local time (and I am not on UTC time.
I've tested this by printing out the calendar's date in a loop, subtracting an hour per loop. It's 11pm on the 19th of May here, and it takes 24 loops before the date changes to the 18th of May. It's currently 1pm UTC, so if the calendar were set properly it would only take 14 loops.

```
    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    int index = 0;
    for(; index > -30; index--)
    {
        System.out.println(index);
        System.out.println(dateFormatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
        System.out.println();
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
    }
```

Comment: possibility duplicate  : http://stackoverflow.com/q/2403109/668970

Comment: I don't believe it's a dupe. Completely different API.

Answer (score 91):

`java.util.Calendar` has a static factory method which takes a timezone.

[`Calendar.getInstance(java.util.TimeZone)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28java.util.TimeZone%29)

So you can say:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Comment: Just in case check if it is first: TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();

Comment: @ssedano Why? We're just setting it to UTC.

Comment: It appears that setting the time zone on the calendar does not affect the SimpleDateFormat object (not surprising since it operates on the Date object).  I had to use `SimpleDateFormat.setTimeZone()` to get it to print out the date interpreted in UTC.