# Date to string is not correnct

Tags: java, android

Probably there will be simply and fast answer but I still cant find out why is the result of

```
Date date = new Date(60000); //one min.
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String dateStr = dateFormat.format(date);
```

dateStr  - 01:01:00
Still one hour more. Time zone? How can I set it without it? Thanks.

Comment: What is the result you are trying for?

Comment: expected result is 00:01:00.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Date` represents a specific moment in time, not a duration. `new Date(60000)` does not create "one minute". See the [docs for that constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29):

> Initializes this Date instance using the specified millisecond value. The value is the number of milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970 GMT.

If you want "one minute from now" you'll probably want to use the `Calendar` class instead, specifically the [`add`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) method.

**Update:**

[`DateUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html) has some useful methods that you might find useful. If you want the elapsed time in HH:mm:ss format, you might try [`DateUtils.formatElapsedTime`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#formatElapsedTime%28long%29). Something like:

```
String dateStr = DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(60);
```

Note that the 60 is in seconds.

Comment: thank you. How can I display difference between two dates? Lets say that date1.getTime() - date2.getTime() = 60000. I want to display it. diffTimeStr = (new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")).format(60000); diffTimeStr is "01:01:00 WHY? Again one hour more.

Comment: @vlkpo java is getting new date apis soon, but for the time being i suggest using the joda time library: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_duration.html

Comment: @vlkpo Again, `Date` is not a duration... I've updated my answer to include something that looks like it matches what you're looking for a little more closely.

Comment: Thank you for your patience:) and DateUtils advice.

Answer (score 1):

Three ways to use `java.util.Date` to specify one minute:

**1. Using** `SimpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))` **as [shahtapa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12667316/938111) said:**

```
Date date = new Date(60*1000); //one min.    
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String dateStr = dateFormat.format(date);
System.out.println("Result = " + dateStr);  //Result should be 00:01:00
```

**2. Using** `java.util.Calendar` **as [kabuko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15213091/938111) said:**

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.clear();
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,1); //one min.
Date date = calendar.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String dateStr = dateFormat.format(date);
System.out.println("Result = " + dateStr);  //Result should be 00:01:00
```

Other `calendar.set()` statements can also be used:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,60*1000);  //one min.
calendar.set(1970,0,1,0,1,0);                //one min.
```

**3. Using these** `setTimeZone` **and** `Calendar` **ideas and forcing** `Calendar` **to** 
***UTC Time-Zone*** 
**as [Simon Nickerson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6059239/938111) said:**

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
calendar.clear();
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,1); //one min.
Date date = calendar.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String dateStr = dateFormat.format(date);
System.out.println("Result = " + dateStr);  //Result should be 00:01:00
```

**Note:** 
 I had a similar issue: Date `1970-01-01` was in my case `-3 600 000` milliseconds (1 hour late) 
 `java.util.Date(70,0,1).getTime() -> -3600000`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use TimeUnit

"A TimeUnit represents time durations at a given unit of granularity and provides utility methods to convert across units, and to perform timing and delay operations in these units. A TimeUnit does not maintain time information, but only helps organize and use time representations that may be maintained separately across various contexts. A nanosecond is defined as one thousandth of a microsecond, a microsecond as one thousandth of a millisecond, a millisecond as one thousandth of a second, a minute as sixty seconds, an hour as sixty minutes, and a day as twenty four hours."

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html

```
Date date = new Date();  // getting actual date
date = new Date (d.getTime() + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1)); // adding one minute to the date
```