# How does time zone relate to access token expiration?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

if i create a new driveservice like this:

```
 public void CreateDriveService()
    {
        string SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        string SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-privatekey.p12");
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, "notasecret",
            X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        var provider = new AssertionFlowClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, certificate)
        {
            ServiceAccountId = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
            Scope = DriveService.Scopes.Drive.GetStringValue(),              
        };

        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(provider, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);
        auth.LoadAccessToken();


        _service = new DriveService(auth);
    }
```

I get a new driveservice, but if i watch the access token it has 29.05.2014 12:25:11 as AccessTokenExpirationUtc but now it is 29.05.2014 13:25:11!
How it is possible???
I already have changed the time zone on google-drive but still same problem....

Thanks in advance

Comment: expand when and where is "now"

Comment: now is at the moment it was created

Comment: will mean that i get an accesstoken that is already expired

Comment: I said "when" and "where". You haven't specified how you are retrieving your version of "now" nor what timezone it refers to

Comment: my timezone is (UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rom, Stockolm, Vienna

Comment: If you're in one of those places, then your current timezone is UTC +2 because of daylight savings

Comment: I think the timezone will not change because of daylight savings

Comment: feel free to think what you like. The time on the access token is one hour ahead of your local time, so you can relax

Comment: Also if i change the timezone in UTC+2 i get access token with AccessTokenExpirationUtc {29.05.2014 14:54:29} and now in my changed time zone it is {29.05.2014 16:54:29}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When comparing any two times, they must have the same timezone. The access token expiration time is given as UTC. If you want to see how far in the future that is, you should compare it with your system's current time in UTC. This question [How to make date.getTime() returns UTC time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403109/how-to-make-date-gettime-returns-utc-time) gives an example of how to do that

Comment: Your right! If i convert the my local time to utc the access token is valid. Thanks a lot