# Time is different between system time and time in log file.

Tags: java, linux, logging, time

I have a web application run on Linux.

The `date` command shows below.

[image]

But the date in my log file is

[image]

The date in my log file is wrong. Why the date is different? How can I fix it? I've restarted my server but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try to get current timezone in your code. You must set the UTC time inside code the same as server UTC timezone. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403109/how-to-make-date-gettime-returns-utc-time

Comment: I use the slf4j + log4j and my PatternLayout is `%d [%7r] %6p:%L - %c - %m \n`. I don't know how to change the timezone in log4j. Besides The date in log file was correct several days ago.

Comment: Did you try https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.html ? `For example, %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS}, %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}, %d{DATE} or %d{HH:mm:ss}{GMT+0}`

Comment: Are you (or your server) in Central America or Saskatchewan? Not many places in the world use CST at this time of year.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the log file times are nearly 12 hours 4 minutes behind the system time?

Comment: With my question about CST I too hastily assumed (American) Central Standard Time. It could also be China Standard Time, Cuba Standard Time or even Australian Central Standard Time.

Comment: Yes, the log file times are exactly 12 hours behind the system time.

Comment: A time zone issue? Assuming CST is UTC-6, your logging framework using a zone offset of UTC-18 would explain. While there is no zone in the world using such an offset, this happens to be the minimum offset Java can work with, so I cannot rule it out completely. You may want to play around with setting the offset explicitly, as @TuanBA suggested, if you have not tried that already.

Answer (score 1):

Unless user specifies the timezone or uses -Duser.timezone  to set the timezone to local time (in your case seems to be CST), JDK would use UTC/GMT as the timezone value by default.